# How to grant user privileges in google cloud using mysql?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench

I have been trying to drop some of my views in my google cloud database
I ran into this error:

ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 74225: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation

Based on this document: https://www.labnol.org/code/revoke-grant-permissions-mysql
I ran this query `SHOW GRANTS FOR root` and I got

```
'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `root`@`%`'
'GRANT `cloudsqlsuperuser`@`%` TO `root`@`%`'
```

I tried to revoke privileges with this command `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM root` but again I ran into another error `'Error Code: 1269. Can't revoke all privileges for one or more of the requested users'`

Is there any solution for how can I grant the user privileges in order to drop tables?
Did I miss something in these commands?

Comment: I do not recommend modifying the Cloud SQL `root` user. Create a new user and apply/delete permissions to that user.

Comment: yes I tested with another user to drop my views, after I drop the first view It shows the permission error again.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm if you altered the users on that instance before?

Also, could you try to do this on a fresh instance, to see if you get the same behavior.

1. Create a totally new, fresh database instance with v5.7.
2. Connect to the database as root@%.
3. Run the Insert/Delete/Drop query and see.

Comment: No, I have not altered the users before I got the permission error.

Comment: It is not possible for me to change the SQL version right now

Comment: Okay don't want to change your SQL version. Just create a new database instance with the previous version you're using now and try it, will work.